# Outputting elements of an array with Arrays.toString()

Tags: java, arrays

I have used the code below to create and populate an array, however, when it comes to printing the array I do not get the result I expect while using the `Arrays.toString()` function.

Rather than printing

```
newArray: [2, 4, 6]
newArray: [8, 10, 12]
etc..
```

it prints

```
newArray: [[I@15db9742, [I@6d06d69c, [I@7852e922, [I@4e25154f]
newArray: [[I@15db9742, [I@6d06d69c, [I@7852e922, [I@4e25154f]
etc..
```

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] newArray = new int[4][3];
    int number = 2;
    for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < newArray.length; rowCounter++) {
        for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter < newArray[rowCounter].length; colCounter++) {
            newArray[rowCounter][colCounter] = number;
            number += 2;
        }
        System.out.println("newArray: " + Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here the result is the address of the array inside the array not the actual values you want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) instead of `toString`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newArray));
```

Comment: @LalitVerma what happen when you use `System.out.println(new int[]{1,2,3});` ?

Comment: @LalitVerma When you use `Arrays.toString` with an array of arrays it will print the arrays inside this array(memory address), and not the values of this arrays

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Arrays.deepToString(newArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

With the result you desire, make sure the array you are declaring is `one-dimensional`. You declared a `two dimensional array` which you are not using correctly.
Change `int[][] newArray to int[] newArray`

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I should have been more clear, the result I have shown is just a snippet of the actual result. In actuality, there are multiple rows. I'll edit this now.

Answer (score 2):

when you call `toString(Object[] a)` internally it will call Object.toString method.

```
(obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

If you want to print all element then as mentioned you have to  `deepToString` instead of `toString` method.Internally it will for a object type array will loop through the array and convert to string.

For an example every array element in your case is int array will call toString.

```
if (eClass.isArray()) {
                    if (eClass == int[].class)
                        buf.append(toString((int[]) element));
```